# Use the stepper motor library with the A4988 driver?

Tags: stepper

I want to use this library: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stepper

```
#include <Stepper.h>
```

The wiring for my driver is shown here:

[image]

https://www.pololu.com/product/1182

From the library, I'm stuck at the motor pins:

```
#define motorSteps 200
#define motorPin1 2    // STEP pin
#define motorPin2 3    // DIR pin

Stepper myStepper(motorSteps, motorPin1, motorPin2);
```

**Is this library not compatible with this stepper motor driver? Or what needs to be defined for it to work?**

More details on the library are here: http://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/circuits/motors/stepper-motors

The basic section of my code that works without the library is this:

```
digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
delay(wait);
digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
delay(wait);
```

Yet, the two-wire circuit part of the library uses motorPin1 and motorPin2 in a way I don't understand:

```
switch (thisStep) {
  case 0:  // 01
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, HIGH);
  break;
  case 1:  // 11
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, HIGH);
  break;
  case 2:  // 10
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, LOW);
  break;
  case 3:  // 00
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, LOW);
  break;
}
```

https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Stepper/blob/master/src/Stepper.cpp

How should `motorPin1` and `motorPin2` be defined?

Answer (score 1):

That library is not compatible with the A4988. It is intended to do the same job that the A4988 does. You provide a step direction and an instruction to step, and it does the stepping for you.

To use the A4988 you just set a pin HIGH or LOW for the direction, then toggle another pin to make it step. You don't really need a library for that.

However if you do want to abstract it with a library and add lots of cool extra features then you should look at [AccelStepper](https://github.com/waspinator/AccelStepper) which supports 2-wire drivers like the A4988.